# why is my if else statement incorrect?

Tags: python, if-statement, input

I am just getting myself used to if else statements in python yet I have some trouble trying to get mine to work, what exactly is happening?

```
x = input("Enter your string")
while not set(x).issubset({'m', 'u', 'i'}):
    print("false")
    x = input("Enter your string")
else:
    print("Your String is " + x)
Question = int(input("Which rule would you like to apply? enter numbers 1-4: "))
if Question is 1:
    print("hello")
    '''issue arises in the else area below'''
else if Question is not 1:
        print("other")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python, you don't write `else if` like you would in C++. You write `elif` as a special keyword.

```
if Question is 1:
    print("hello")
elif Question is not 1:
    print("other")
```

Comment: You should not use `is` to compare numbers.

Comment: @JBernardo, true but that wasn't causing the problem in this question

Comment: Also `elif` is redundant if you are using it to recheck the same condition you just checked.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
else if Question is not 1:
```

should read

```
elif Question is not 1:
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the if...else statement is −

```
if expression(A):
   //whatever 
elif expression(B):
   //whatever 
else:
  //whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you ought to be writing in this case is:

```
if Question==1:
    print("hello")
else:
    print("other")
```

You don't need to `if` check that `Question` is not 1, because that is what `else` means: that the `if` statement above it did not match.

Also, use `==` to compare numbers, not `is`.

In a circumstance where you do need `else if`, the Python keyword is `elif`.

```
if Question==1:
    print("hello")
elif Question==2:
    print("goodbye")
else:
    print("other")
```

Comment: @joelgoldstick Actually `q is 1` checks if `q` is the same object as this other `int` with value `1`, which in practice will work for `1`, but is still generally the wrong way to compare numbers.